# Как сделать, чтобы элемент двигался вместе scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, html, javascript

Здравствуйте. Я хочу поставить div element вверху страницу, а когда буду изменять scrooll, то элемент должен вместе с ним двигаться.

Comment: А я пробовал, у меня работьает только в Опере!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Элементу Нужно установить фиксированное позиционнирование 
Например

```
#main{
position:fixed;
}
или
<div style="position:fixed;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<title>Фиксированный слой</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   #menu {
    position: fixed; /* Фиксированное положение */
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">Меню</div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство CSS **position:fixed;** у необходимого div-блока.
Есть интересный пример [Animated Scroll to Top](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/animated-scroll-to-top) ([Demo](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/scroll-to-top/scrolltotop.html)).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="slideBarLeft"></div>
```

и

```
$(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {

        if (getBrowserStrict() == "IE") {
            var sly = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        } else {
            var sly = window.scrollY;
        }; // end if else
        setTimeout(delayScroll, 700);

        function delayScroll() {
            $('#slideBarLeft').stop().animate({
                'top': sly + 'px'
            }, 700);
        };

    }); //end scroll
}); // end ready
```

Пример по ссылке: http://fonts.kobru.ru/.